# Render ModelAndView manually?

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I need to render ModelAndView in my controller manually in order to put it inside JSON object. If I pass the whole ModelAndView object into to JSON I get " no serializer found for class javassistlazyinitializer" exception because jackson can't work properly with LAZY-objects.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class JSONView implements View {
    /**
     * Logger for this class
     */
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JSONView.class);

    private String contentType = "application/json";

    public void render(Map map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("render(Map, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) - start");
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write(jsonObject.toString());

    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("render(Map, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) - end");
    }
    }

    public String getContentType() {
    return contentType;
    }

}
```

`ModelAndView returnModelAndView = new ModelAndView(new JSONView(), model);`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have found some another ViewResolver - MappingJacksonJsonView. But can not configure it. Is says that resolver does not run in an application context, but I added it in config file. Any ideas? THank you

Comment: The problem is that with lazy-collections it fails. So I am trying to find any solution of manual view rendering. Then, I just put it into JSON object as String

Comment: Actually no. What I need is to be able return (from controller) some JSON structure where one of the fields will be the ModelAndView object. Does your solution allow this?

Comment: Could you post the whole post includins import definitions and configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Actually from the configuration and whole part is bit lengthy... If you insist then I can write it on my blog... Otherwise it would be much complex to post here... As there are DAO implementation and Service Layer integration with the controller???

Comment: THanks for your reply. I'll be glad if you post it on your blog. Waiting for this post. But I repeat - I need some implementation that can return JSON object where one od the fields should be rendered ModelAndView object. I hope your solution solves my problem. Thanks again

Comment: Ok... Before posting... I'll post it may be Sunday... But before that... I want to share with you some of the things like you need to put your desired strings or objects in a HashMap or Map implementations and then just return that Map in the JSONView from ModelAndView constructor. And that is just the basic of implementing the return of JSONView in SpringMVC...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement it anyway. But first - are you sure that your implementation handles a LAZY-collections? I mean is it returns properly all lazy-objects too?

Comment: Man, I am working with an Enterpise Software... And it is working... And the system is in live... :)

Comment: So I am really waiting for your post:)

Comment: may be you can post some zip-file with simple demo earlier than sunday? I need it yesterday if you know what I mean:)

Comment: http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com/2011/07/spring-mvc-json-example.html is the URL where I have given the detailed explanation. That is actually on the fly. Because I am little bit busy working on some other projects. Any comments related to that just post over there in my blog post.